# Why do i get the TypeError "argument of type 'type' is not iterable"?

Tags: python, if-statement, dictionary, testing, typeerror

I am trying to add some keys to my dictionary after testing if they are already existing keys. But I seem not to be able to do the test, every time I get the `TypeError "argument of type 'type' not iterable`.

This is basically my code:

```
dictionary = dict
sentence = "What the heck"
for word in sentence:
      if not word in dictionary:
             dictionary.update({word:1})
```

I also tried `if not dictionary.has_key(word)` but it didn't work either so I am really confused.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
dictionary = dict
```

That creates a reference to the *type object* `dict`, not an empty dictionary. That type object is indeed not iterable:

```
>>> 'foo' in dict
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument of type 'type' is not iterable
```

Use `{}` instead:

```
dictionary = {}
```

You could also have used `dict()` (calling the type to produce an empty dictionary), but the `{}` syntax is preferred (it is faster and easier to scan for visually in a piece of code).

You also have an issue with your `for` loop; looping over as string gives you the individual letters, *not* words:

```
>>> for word in "the quick":
...     print(word)
...
t
h
e

q
u
i
c
k
```

If you wanted words, you could split on whitespace with `str.split()`:

```
for word in sentence.split():
```

Comment: You may also want to change the for loop to loop over the words it the sentence rather than the letters, as I added above

Comment: @MarkBakker: added.

Comment: @MarkBakker: that did not need to be a suggested edit, however. It could have been left to a comment on the question, but the focus of the post here is the exact error message.

Comment: Thank you so much! I did'nt even thougt about that the error could be up there. It worked now!